# import/require image or public folder?

Tags: javascript, html, image, webpack, es6-modules

In a webpack React project, I can add an image through

`<img src={require('./img.png'}/>` (equivalent to using `import`)

or

`<img src='img.png'/>` and put the image in the `public` folder.

What's the difference between the two and which is preferred?

From my testing it seems like the browser will cache the image only if it's in `public` folder?

Answer (score 0):

The second one is preferred. Public directory stores static assets. Its part of webpack's philosophy. And I think u dont want to add an annoying "require" in the src attribute of .